# activity_main error

Tags: java, android

`Activity_main.xml` is present but still its giving a error in `MainActivity.java`
Can anyone tell me what is the error here?

```
package com.example.hellotabwidget;

import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

> activity_main cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: Please post part of your code when you trying to use it.

Comment: have u clean or build ur project before run????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is simply change this line:

```
import android.R;
```

to this line (if `com.example.hellotabwidget` is base package of your app)

```
import com.example.hellotabwidget.R;
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the line

```
import android.R;
```

and import the `R` for appropriate package

in this line

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

Comment: write "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)" again and after writing R press ctrl+space it ll automatically import the appropriate package.

Answer (score 1):

Clean your project workspace and rebuild once

Answer (score 0):

**Golden sentence:**

Take care of **import android.R;**, it imports built-in R file, it doesn't require in your project unless you want to access built-in resources.

More about: [android.R](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.html) or [here](http://www.yugandroid.in/android-tutorials/r-java-file.html).